Woocommerce 'Select Option' Popup
I am trying to add a popup modal on 'select option' button in a woocommerce website. I want my customer to click 'select option' button to see variation and add products on product pages.
But, the 'Add to Cart' button is clicked, the product is not added to cart or mini-cart, while popup works fine though.
The code is here.
add-to-cart.php
<?php


if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

global $product;
global $woocommerce;

// var_dump($product);
$variation_ids = array();
$target_attribute = 'sizes';

if ( 'variable' === $product->get_type() ) {
    ?>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <!-- Modal Trigger Button for "Select options" -->
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary select-options" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo esc_attr( $product->slug ); ?>">
        <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Select Options
    </a>

    <!-- Modal Structure -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->slug ); ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->slug ); ?>Label" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->slug ); ?>Label">Select Options</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form id="variation-form-<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>" class="variation-form">
                        <?php
                        $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
                        foreach ( $available_variations as $variation ) {
                            $variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
                            $price = wc_price( $variation['display_price'] );
                            ?>
                            <div class="variation-option">
                                <input type="radio" name="selected_variation" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $variation_id ); ?>" id="variation-<?php echo esc_attr( $variation_id ); ?>">
                                <label for="variation-<?php echo esc_attr( $variation_id ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo wp_kses_post( implode( ' ', $variation['attributes'] ) . ' - ' . $price ); ?>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add-to-cart" data-product-id="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>">Add to Cart</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
} else {
    echo apply_filters(
        'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', // WPCS: XSS ok.
        sprintf(
            '<a href="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="%s" %s>%s</a>',
            esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
            esc_attr( isset( $args['quantity'] ) ? $args['quantity'] : 1 ),
            esc_attr( isset( $args['class'] ) ? $args['class'] : 'button' ),
            isset( $args['attributes'] ) ? wc_implode_html_attributes( $args['attributes'] ) : '',
            esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
        ),
        $product,
        $args
    );
}

/JS/select-option-popup.js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.select-options').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let targetModal = $(this).data('target');
        $(targetModal).modal('show');
    });

    $('.add-to-cart').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        let productId = $(this).data('product-id');
        let selectedVariation = $('input[name="selected_variation"]:checked').val();

        // Make sure a variation is selected
        if (!selectedVariation) {
            alert("Please select an option.");
            return;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart',
                product_id: productId,
                variation_id: selectedVariation,
                quantity: 1,
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.error && response.product_url) {
                    window.location.href = response.product_url;
                    return;
                }

                // Trigger mini cart update
                $(document.body).trigger('added_to_cart', [response.fragments, response.cart_hash]);
                alert("Product added to cart!");

                // Close the modal
                $('.modal').modal('hide');
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("There was an error adding the product to the cart. Please try again.");
            }
        });
    });
});

function.php

function custom_enqueue_select_popup_js() {
    if (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag()) {
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'select-option-popup', // Handle for the script
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/select-option-popup.js', // Updated file path
            array('jquery'),
            null,
            true
        );

        wp_localize_script('select-option-popup', 'ajax_object', array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
        ));
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_select_popup_js');

// AJAX Handler
function custom_add_to_cart_ajax_handler() {
    $product_id = isset($_POST['product_id']) ? absint($_POST['product_id']) : 0;
    $variation_id = isset($_POST['variation_id']) ? absint($_POST['variation_id']) : 0;

    if ($product_id && $variation_id) {
        $added = WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, 1, $variation_id);

        if ($added) {
            WC_AJAX::get_refreshed_fragments(); // Update mini-cart fragments
            wp_send_json_success(array('message' => 'Product added to cart!'));
        } else {
            wp_send_json_error(array('message' => 'Failed to add product to cart.'));
        }
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error(array('message' => 'Invalid product or variation ID.'));
    }
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_add_to_cart', 'custom_add_to_cart_ajax_handler');
add_action('wp_ajax_custom_add_to_cart', 'custom_add_to_cart_ajax_handler');

//Enable AJAX Add to Cart for Variable Products
function enable_ajax_add_to_cart_for_variable_products() {
    // Enable AJAX for variable products
    add_filter('woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart', '__return_true');
}
add_action('init', 'enable_ajax_add_to_cart_for_variable_products');

// Enqueue Bootstrap CSS and JavaScript
function enqueue_bootstrap_for_modals() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_bootstrap_for_modals' );

Edit: Adding a screenshot for the modal
enter image description here
If you could share your insight. I would really appreciate it.

You have action: 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart', where your handler is custom_add_to_cart_ajax_handler
